# How to merge tabular data in PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, foreach

I have a table with weeks of a year and some data adjacent to each week, and i can't seem to merge the values correctly. Week rows with no data should stay empty

This is where i list the weeks

```
       foreach ($getLeadCountDMm as $index => $leadCount) { ?>
               <tr>
                <td><?php echo $leadCount->theweek ?>
                   / <?php echo $leadCount->theyear ?></td>
               </tr>
              <?php }
```

And this is where i try to merge

```
      foreach ($getLeadCountDMm as $index => $leadCount) { ?>
        <tr>
         <td style="text-align: center">
         <?php if ($getFtdCountDMm[$index]->theweek == $leadCount->theweek && !empty($getFtdCountDMm[$index]->ftdcount)) {
          echo $getFtdCountDMm[$index]->ftdcount;
            } else {
               echo '0';
                } ?>
             </td>
          </tr>
       <?php } ?>
```

[it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3AAO.png)

[but it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXcSA.png)

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I don't get an error. I posted images of how it looks VS how it should look

Comment: I don't think this is related to your issue but is `$getFtdCountDMm[$index]->theweek == $leadCount->theweek` always true?

Comment: yes, i pass the same dates in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running two loops run one loop like this.

```
foreach ($getLeadCountDMm as $index => $leadCount) { ?>
                   <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $leadCount->theweek ?>
                       / <?php echo $leadCount->theyear ?>
                   </td>

                   <td style="text-align: center">
                    <?php if ($getFtdCountDMm[$index]->theweek == $leadCount->theweek && !empty($getFtdCountDMm[$index]->ftdcount)) {
              echo $getFtdCountDMm[$index]->ftdcount;
                } else {
                   echo '0';
                    } ?>
                 </td>

                   </tr>
                  <?php }
```